# Joda DateTime parsing full date name

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

```
import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format._

val pattern = "MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
val input = "Apr 10 18:31:45 +0000 2015"
DateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern))
```

anyone can tell me why it doesnt work ?

I get :

```
DateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Apr 10 18:31:45 +0000 2015"
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
  at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:160)
  ... 43 elided
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val pattern = "MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
val input = "Apr 10 18:31:45 +0000 2015"

val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
format.parseDateTime(input)
```

I found out nvm ;)